# Azure web activity error public access is not permitted

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to access my storage account with data factory web activity.
When I run the pipeline it through the error: public access is not permitted on this storage account.

I am trying to use Managed Identities for the web activity to authenticate to the Storage without having to make it public. They are both in the same virtual network.

Any idea where it could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that both resources are connected to Virtual network.
You may achieve that by creating Private Endpoints for both your Storage Account and Azure Data Factory.

If ADF doesn't have private endpoint it will connect over public network.

MaayanY,
there is a setting that may prevent you from accessing Blob, can you check your configuration?
[image: Azure Storage Account configuration pane]

Documentation reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal

Comment: Hi, thank for the response! Both of the resources connected to the same virtual network with private endpoints and it's still not working. Is there more configuration that need to be done?

Comment: hi, I want to secure my storage account so I purposely disabled this option. From my knowledge the web activity supposed to be able to access resoucres in virtual network.

Comment: What runtime do you use to execute pipeline?
You should use one that enables you to create private endpoint connection either Azure or Self-hosted.

I tired to recreate your scenario and I couldn't connect with Autoresolve Integration runtime but it worked with one that connects to Managed network and created private endpoint to the storage account

Comment: Hi Greg, I use Self-Hosted